# Using vue js components when using it from cdn

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to use the ButtonCounter component as an example (https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#defining-a-component), but I just can't make it work. I use vue js 3 from a CDN.

I have the ButtonCounter.js file:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  template: `
    <button @click="count++">
      You clicked me {{ count }} times.
    </button>`
}
```

Then I have the main js file with vue:

```
import ButtonCounter from './ButtonCounter.js'


const app = Vue.createApp({
  components: {
    ButtonCounter
  },

  data() {
    return {
      aaa: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...
  }
}
})

app.mount('#app')
```

And finally I have the html where I link vue js from a cdn, and I specify the following inside the body:

```
<ButtonCounter />
```

But I can't see the button. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/?redirect=true#Component-name-casing-in-templates-strongly-recommended  . You can't use ButtonCounter  outside vue templates because html is case-insensitive

Comment: Note that I use vue 3, and I think my casing is fine.

Comment: This isn't different in 3 because this isn't Vue's but browser's limitation. If you know the cause of your problem, then why asking?

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I managed to solve it by using the vue-loader project, see https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue3-sfc-loader. It's a great tool!

index.html:

```
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue3-sfc-loader@0.8.4/dist/vue3-sfc-loader.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  ....
  <ButtonCounter />
</div>

<script src="/main.js"></script>
```

main.js:

```
const { loadModule } = window['vue3-sfc-loader'];

const VueLoaderOpts = {
  moduleCache: { vue: Vue },
  async getFile(url) {
    const res = await fetch(url)
    if(!res.ok)
       throw Object.assign(new Error(url+' '+res.statusText), { res });
    return await res.text();
  },
  addStyle: () => {},
}

const app = Vue.createApp({
  components: {
    'ButtonCounter': Vue.defineAsyncComponent(() => loadModule('./ButtonCounter.vue', VueLoaderOpts))
  },

  data() {
    ...
  }
}
```

ButtonCounter.vue:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="count++">
    You clicked me {{ count }} times yet.
  </button>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you put inside the `<div id=app></div>` in the index.html is over-written when you have mounted your vue application.

It should work if you put it in the template of your main.js file:

```
import ButtonCounter from './ButtonCounter.js'
const app = Vue.createApp({
    components: {
        ButtonCounter
    },
    template: `<ButtonCounter />`
})

app.mount('#app')
```

Note that if you have not said `type=module` on the script tag for your main.js then it will blow up when you try to import

Comment: Yes, I use type=module. However, when I add the template: `` part I can see the button, but only the button, and my whole html stuff can't be seen anymore.

Comment: Also, I don't use SFC, because I use vue 3 from a cdn (specified in index.html) to spare the build using npm. So I don't have a template for main.js

Comment: You should probably add your full index.html to your question. To me, your description  of the problem sounds exactly like what I was describing with the over-writing.
You can have a sibling div to the div which has the class="app" which contains html that will not be over written by the template.
Before I answered, I recreated this demo project, using Vue 3 from the CDN - no build step.

Comment: Can you show me an example how to do that, I'm somewhat confused. Also, can I read the template html stuff from an external file?

Comment: Thank you for your clues, @tazhinkle, I managed to solve it eventually.

Answer (score 0):

This is only an advice but you can using SFC in Vue 3 using a helper from [this package](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue3-sfc-loader)

And on the script when you initialize Vue, you can use it like this, for example:

app.js

```
 // Setup vue-sfc-loader
const options = {
    moduleCache: {
        vue: Vue,
    },
    async getFile(url) {
        const res = await fetch(url);
        if (!res.ok)
            throw Object.assign(new Error(res.statusText + " " + url), { res });
        return {
            getContentData: (asBinary) =>
                asBinary ? res.arrayBuffer() : res.text(),
        };
    },
    addStyle(textContent) {
        const style = Object.assign(document.createElement("style"), {
            textContent,
        });
        const ref = document.head.getElementsByTagName("style")[0] || null;
        document.head.insertBefore(style, ref);
    },
};

const { loadModule } = window["vue3-sfc-loader"];
// END Setup vue-sfc-loader

const base_component_url = '/static/assets/dashboard/js/vue/';

function load(path) {
    return Vue.defineAsyncComponent(() => loadModule(base_component_url + path, options))
}

const app = Vue.createApp({ 
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'], 
    components: {
        'Greeting': load('components/test/Greeting.vue')
    }
});

app.mount('#__VUE');
```

and call the component on your html like:

```
<Greeting></Greeting>
```

or

```
<Greeting />
```